# Google Cloud Run generate public key and private key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openssl, google-cloud-run, private-key, public-key

Is it possible to generate Open SSL key for our Google Cloud Run instance? Currently I need it to integrate with external API that ask for our public key

Comment: You can do what you want with Cloud Run, as long as you comply with the runtime contract.

Comment: Clarify what you mean. There are many use cases for public keys and there are several types of public keys. For the most part, Cloud Run does not care how your application authenticates with another service. Edit your post so that we know the correct details.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this documentation on [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run):

> Cloud Run is a managed compute platform that lets you run containers directly on top of Google's scalable infrastructure.
>
> You can deploy code written in any programming language on Cloud Run
> if you can build a container image from it. In fact, building
> container images is optional. If you're using Go, Node.js, Python,
> Java, .NET Core, or Ruby, you can use the [source-based deployment](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code)
> option that builds the container for you, using the best practices for
> the language you're using.

@guillaumeblaquiere is correct that you can do anything with Cloud Run as long as we adhere with the [container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract). This contains few differences between [Cloud Run services](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/run-targets) and [Cloud Run jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs).

You may also check this [criteria if your app is a good fit for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/fit-for-run).